# Websphere 8.5.5 with enabled Java 1.7.0 and Struts facet (RSA 9.0)

Tags: java-7, struts-1, websphere-8, rational-rsa

If someone has the same problem:

```
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R java.lang.NumberFormatException: null [11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:466) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at java.lang.Integer.(Integer.java:689) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.struts.action.ModuleConfigXmlParser.startElement(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)     
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.struts.action.ModuleConfigXmlParser.parse(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(Unknown Source) 
[11.02.16. 15:19:22:427 CET] 00000057 SystemErr R at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(Unknown Source)
```

Java 7 was enabled on existing profile.
Deployed application and IDE behaved strangely.

I tried many various options (changing class loading policy, changing build path JREs, removing struts support, deleting wstemp folder, putting xerces and xalan jars inside WEB-INF/lib folder) but nothing seems to work.

I was able to resolve this by enabling Java 7 again and AFTER that by creation of new WAS profile.

Comment: You might want to copy the last bit into an answer and mark it accepted. That will help people see it as solved rather than open [at a glance]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by enabling Java 7 again and AFTER that by creation of new WAS profile.